# React Native (newer version): "Unable to resolve module"

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

I'm new to React-Native and use the Expo xde GUI. I had no problems up to the point, I wanted to use external modules at. I installed them using `npm install module`. Next I wanted to import them into my App.js file using `import Module from 'module'` But after starting the project I got the following error in the Expo Client App on the iOS Simulator:

> Unable to resolve module `react-renderif` from `/Users/my_name/Desktop/ExpoProjekte/test/App.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
>   /Users/my_name/node-modules
>
> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
>
> ABI25_0_0RCTFatal
>   **37-[ABI25_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>   _dispatch_client_callout
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
>   __CFRunLoopRun CFRunLoopRunSpecific GSEventRunModal UIApplicationMain main start 0x0

I tried all tipps mentioned in the error message, but nothing helped. I also tried out many workarounds described on the internet (e.g. in this forum), but this also didn't lead to success. The problem occurs with all modules that I tried to install and to import, e.g. react-renderif and native-base.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? I know that the question was asked several times in this forum, but the answers didn't help me, maybe because they only worked for older versions.

Regards,
Paul

**Desktop operating system:** MacOS Sierra (`10.12.6`)
**Expo version:** `2.22.1`
**npm version:** `4.6.1` and `5.6.0` (I tried out both)
**My package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.3.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 react-native upgrade
```

or, `react-native-git-upgrade`

Note: Use this only if u have no way out since .It will clear all the changes you did in ios and android folder rest will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but both commands don't work with the error message 'command not found' in the terminal. Any idea why?

Comment: Aren't you working in react native project ? 
If So, That is impossible !!
Didn't you run it inside your project directory ?

Comment: Also to use git-upgrade you need set  up the package and have backup in git.

Comment: Thanks for this tipp. I always ran the terminal commands globally, but not in the specific project directory. In the aftermath that appears to be very stupid, but as a beginner with react-native (and the terminal) I didn't  know it better. By running 'npm install module' in the project directory the error message disappears.

Comment: We are allowed to make mistakes in our life . That is how we learn new things . M glad I could help you . I was going to ask you to do rm  node module & npm install but as u mentioned early you have already done that so I ddn't mentioned it .